# How to use the "Combo" tool?

Tags: modifiers

I have been following a tutorial and since this tutorial is really old (2009), the person used a tool called "combo" to extrude and rotate at the same time, without moving the rest of the body.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUifORl-faI

The part that I'm stuck is around 7:20.
Does this tool still exists in the 2.79 version? If not, what can I use to have a similar result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press Shift and click each of the manipulator types to add them to the widget, and this will allow you to have the 'Combo' that they show in the video.
[image: combo]

Answer (score 1):

The *Combo* is just a combined display of the manipulator (translate, rotate and scale), you won't find it as tool or operator. You do the same in 2.79 by selecting them all with <kbd>Shift</kbd>:

[image]